# Create-React-App Unexpected Connection Refused

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I keep getting the below error when I try to simply create a new react app. I even set up fiddler on my computer and set my proxy to work with that but I am still getting the following error:

> ECONNREFUSED 13.107.6.183:443

Click [here](https://ufile.io/fsbhvdh9) for the complete log

```
$ create-react-app testmeup

Creating a new React app in C:\***\source\Dev\testmeup.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

yarn add v1.15.2
[1/4] Resolving packages...
error An unexpected error occurred: "https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/AdmInvestorServices/_packaging/test/npm/registry/react: connect ECONNREFUSED 13.107.6.183:443".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "C:\\****\\source\\Dev\\testmeup\\yarn-error.log".
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/add for documentation about this command.

Aborting installation.
  yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom react-scripts --cwd C:\Users\***\Dev\testmeup has failed.

Deleting generated file... package.json
Deleting generated file... yarn.lock
Done.
```

Comment: Did you check "C:\\Users\\A778765\\source\\Dev\\testmeup\\yarn-error.log" ???

Comment: Yes, I attached into my question that file.

Comment: Sorry this is not a secured link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be an *issue with your proxy settings* since when you're running `create-react-app <app_name>` `yarn` is unable to resolve the necessary dependencies to set up your new `react` project, namely: `react`, `react-dom`, and `react-scripts`.

Maybe you could try setting your proxy settings so you can install the necessary libraries `create-react-app` needs. According to `yarn's` [documentation](https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/envvars):

*"For backward compatiibilty with npm, Yarn allows passing down npm configuration via environment variables."*

So maybe you could try the following and seeing if this helps resolve your issue:

```
npm config set proxy <proxy_url>
npm config set https-proxy <proxy_url>
```

where the `<proxy_url>` is changed to work with your appropriate proxy. Then you can tell `yarn` to ignore ssl if necessary. **Note**: Use at your own discretion.

```
yarn config set strict-ssl false
```

`npm config set <key> <value>` sets `npm` environment variables which `yarn` can also utilize. In this particular case we are setting the `proxy` environment variables. Now simply try running the `create-react-app` command again and it should be able to proceed with setting up the new `react` project for you.

Hopefully that helps!