# error An unexpected error occurred: while creating a new react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

hello guys i am new in react js Am getting an error when i creating an react app below i share my error screenshot please checkout and try to fix my error

error screenshot https://ibb.co/rtXs5yv

Comment: What have you tried? There's other posts about this, like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55795574/create-react-app-unexpected-connection-refused Also include the actual error message here, never *pictures* of errors (or code)

Comment: yes sir getting same error

Comment: It is trying to download the package from the localhost. Do you have a host file configuration?

Comment: no i have no host file configuration